# How can I activate the USB ports on my laptop (Ryzen, Ubuntu, kernel 5.11., no power at all)?

Tags: usb, power-management

I have a problem with my Thinkpad T14s running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. First I experienced this problem a few months back. When I connected an optical drive via cable or my smartphone nothing happens. The smartphone is also not loading the battery. And also I could not access any USB flash drives.

Previously I downgraded to the 5.8.0-50-generic kernel (but this was just an attempt, as I am not really knowing what I was doing there). For a short while it seemed to work, but then again it stopped. Just recently I upgrade to 5.11.0-40-generic #44~20.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 26 18:07:44 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux.
I have no idea what to check to narrow down the problem. On other computers all of these USB devices work and it is same disfunctionality for both USB ports of my laptop.

I guess, you might ask for the output of certain commands. I will try to deliver those directly here.

```
lsusb
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 003: ID 8087:0029 Intel Corp. 
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 06cb:00bd Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 058f:9540 Alcor Micro Corp. AU9540 Smartcard Reader
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04f2:b6cb Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated Camera
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
lsusb -v > lsusbvoutput
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
can't get device qualifier: Resource temporarily unavailable
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
```

```
sudo uhubctl
Current status for hub 3 [1d6b:0003 Linux 5.8.0-50-generic xhci-hcd xHCI Host Controller 0000:05:00.0, USB 3.00, 2 ports]
  Port 1: 02a0 power 5gbps Rx.Detect
  Port 2: 02a0 power 5gbps Rx.Detect
Current status for hub 2 [1d6b:0002 Linux 5.8.0-50-generic xhci-hcd xHCI Host Controller 0000:05:00.0]
  Port 1: 0100 power
  Port 2: 0507 power highspeed suspend enable connect [04f2:b6cb Chicony Electronics Co.,Ltd. Integrated Camera 0001]
```

When the USB ports worked for a while I could also make a diff of lsusb:

```
496c496
< Bus 004 Device 002: ID 058f:9540 Alcor Micro Corp. AU9540 Smartcard Reader
---
> Bus 004 Device 003: ID 058f:9540 Alcor Micro Corp. AU9540 Smartcard Reader
592a593,650
>         bInterval               0
> 
> Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0e8d:1887 MediaTek Inc. Portable Super Multi Drive
> Device Descriptor:
>   bLength                18
>   bDescriptorType         1
>   bcdUSB               2.00
>   bDeviceClass            0 
>   bDeviceSubClass         0 
>   bDeviceProtocol         0 
>   bMaxPacketSize0        64
>   idVendor           0x0e8d MediaTek Inc.
>   idProduct          0x1887 
>   bcdDevice            0.00
>   iManufacturer           1 
>   iProduct                2 
>   iSerial                 3 
>   bNumConfigurations      1
>   Configuration Descriptor:
>     bLength                 9
>     bDescriptorType         2
>     wTotalLength       0x0020
>     bNumInterfaces          1
>     bConfigurationValue     1
>     iConfiguration          4 
>     bmAttributes         0xa0
>       (Bus Powered)
>       Remote Wakeup
>     MaxPower              500mA
>     Interface Descriptor:
>       bLength                 9
>       bDescriptorType         4
>       bInterfaceNumber        0
>       bAlternateSetting       0
>       bNumEndpoints           2
>       bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
>       bInterfaceSubClass      2 SFF-8020i, MMC-2 (ATAPI)
>       bInterfaceProtocol     80 
>       iInterface              5 
>       Endpoint Descriptor:
>         bLength                 7
>         bDescriptorType         5
>         bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
>         bmAttributes            2
>           Transfer Type            Bulk
>           Synch Type               None
>           Usage Type               Data
>         wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
>         bInterval               0
>       Endpoint Descriptor:
>         bLength                 7
>         bDescriptorType         5
>         bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
>         bmAttributes            2
>           Transfer Type            Bulk
>           Synch Type               None
>           Usage Type               Data
>         wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
```

I hope I provided enough details and that you can help me.

Best regards

Comment: Before anything else: Update UEFI

Comment: I will google how to do that.

Comment: Better go directly to the manufacturer's website, look for drivers and "BIOS" (actually UEFI) and follow instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Update: After not rebooting, but really shutting down the computer, starting in recovery mode with the current kernel 5.11.0-40-generic, it worked again. Then I started the same kernel without recovery mode and it stills works. Don't know why, but I am glad about it. Thanks for your advice!